# Share java object in memory between instances

Tags: java

I have an object that is the mapping of a COBOL memory structure, the idea is to use it so i can read a COBOL fixed length file in java. I want the object to be shared along all the instances of java programs, so i don't need to load it from disk every time someone starts an instance of the java program.

The java program will be called from another COBOL program, using "system" (cmd or terminal), it will basically serve to save data into an SQL database.

Use case:

In COBOL, a variable is strctured like this:

```
01 USER-INFORMATION.
   02 USER-B-DAY.
      03 B-DAY   PIC 9(02).
      03 B-MONTH PIC 9(02).
      03 B-YEAR  PIC 9(04).
   02 USER-NAME  PIC X(50).
```

When saving a user with:
Name      = Toniotti
Birth Day = 11/06/2002

The data will be this: 11062002Toniotti

I want to be able to read this in Java (and create a User object, with all the "properties"/variables), i will be able to this by having the variable structure mapped, so i can determine that from the data "string", in position 0 to 6 i have the birth day of the user and it needs to be an integer (PIC 9).
My problem is that reading a file with the mapped variable all the time will slow down the process. It needs to be the fast as possible as i'am already adding time by saving the data later, in a sql database.
The first option i have is to store the mapping in a in-memory database, but i want to know if there is another faster option that i can use.

I don't need to use java so if you know another program language that is able to do that, i would appreciate to know the name and how it's made.

The maximum size of the data is about 200kb.The variable structure in the cobol program has a little more than 2000 lines (about 2000 variables).The OS is IBM AIX. It needs to be so fast, because it has about 100k requests per day.

Comment: You can use single Object for that. So it will have only single copy of the object.

Comment: You cannot simply "share" objects through multiple instances of Java processes, but what is possible is to write a standalone Java program that runs all the time representing that object/connection to the database and your other programs can then call that program to perform the action you mention - kinda like a device driver. To help you more we need more info on the use-case and the "interface" of that object.

Comment: The term you're going to want to search for is 'java interprocess communication' or 'java ipc'.  There's a lot of routes you can take to allow multiple instances of java to share information between one another, or other routes you can take where the COBOL program will communicate to a long-running java programme instead of launching a new one each time.  Without more information (OS, how big the data is, what are your biggest concerns - speed, atomicity, etc.) I'm afraid people won't be able to suggest a 'best one' for you.

Comment: hm, a memory mapped file comes to mind. It's not 100% the requirement as it is not strictly in memory, that is up to the OS.

Comment: This java ipc will allow me to directly access objects in memory of another program? My biggest concern is speed, i thought about in-memory databases, but i'am trying to find the fastest way of doing it (in terms of processing time). The data size will be a maximum of 200kb and the OS is IBM AIX.

Comment: As long as you haven't added more detail what exactly your use-case is nobody can properly help you (and no, you can not access the memory of arbitrary programs on your machine and assume it to be a Java program :-) )

Comment: @Toniotti If you biggest concern is speed, then do not start any java programs on demand (that is much slower than the crudest form of inter-process communication), but have one java program permanently running. And forget about shared memory, that will give you endless synchronization headaches.

Comment: How large is your memory structure?

Comment: I added some more information, and a use case. @NomadMaker it has about 2000 variables.

Comment: If that's a constant, it should be unnoticeable creating that in Java.

Comment: It can actually change overtime(like months), and it will look terrible having an entire object hard coded.